# When client browse mvc website and server is processing heavily and client close page

Tags: process

I have an idea that a client post a url to server, and asp.net mvc action server download the file in that url, in this process the server might not returning anything to client and the client will see loading page.

If the client choose to close the page in the browser, will the process in the server terminated or throw exception or will the server keep downloading the file until the process terminated normally?

I have two idea
1. Client browse a url, server download files for client while client does not need to wait just choose to close the page, the server download files for client and email client when file finished downloading
2. Client browse a url with a torrent file, server download the torrent for the client and client can choose the close the page and once server finished downloading the torrent, server will email client.

Can above be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES
the server will keep running the process, I have tried it and the server successfully downloading any file I instruct it to download for me, either via torrent or via direct download.

Hopes this help someone